# Why am I getting weird values in text boxes?

Tags: php, mysql

What's wrong in this code, its showing weird value in both subject and message text box, but they should be empty. Server is giving me Undefined Variable error Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation something. Please take a look, I'm a php beginner. Please help me get rid of those values in the text boxes. They should be empty.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$from = 'drstoic@xyz.com';
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$text = $_POST['newsletter_content'];
$output_form = false;

if (empty($subject) && empty($text)) {
// We know both $subject AND $text are blank 
  echo 'You forgot the email subject and body text.<br />';
  $output_form = true;
}

if (empty($subject) && (!empty($text))) {
  echo 'You forgot the email subject.<br />';
  $output_form = true;
}

if ((!empty($subject)) && empty($text)) {
  echo 'You forgot the email body text.<br />';
  $output_form = true;
}
}
else {
$output_form = true;
}

  if ((!empty($subject)) && (!empty($text))) {
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'a12345', 'pocr')
  or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

$query = "SELECT * FROM email_list";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
  or die('Error querying database.');

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $to = $row['email'];
  $first_name = $row['first_name'];
  $last_name = $row['last_name'];
  $msg = "Dear $first_name $last_name,\n$text";
  mail($to, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $from);
  echo 'Email sent to: ' . $to . '<br />';
} 

mysqli_close($dbc);
}
if ($output_form)
{ 
?> <form method="post"  action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"                    
<label for="subject">Subject:</label> 
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="input_field" 
value="<?php echo $subject; ?>" />
<div class="cleaner h10"></div>

<label for="newsletter_content">Message:</label> 
<textarea id="newsletter_content" name="newsletter_content" rows="0" cols="0"><?php echo $text; ?></textarea>

<div class="cleaner h10"></div>

<input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" name="submit" class="submit_btn float_l" />
<input type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset" name="reset" class="submit_btn float_r" />

</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: set `$text = ''; $subject = '';` at the top of your page before `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {`

Comment: Probably the missing closing `>` in `<form method="post"  action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` try `<form method="post"  action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">` which is contributing.

Comment: Also be careful when breaking up your inputs into seperate lines `<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="input_field" 
value="<?php echo $subject; ?>" />`

Comment: Sidenote: Your closing brace `}` for `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` is not in the right place. Everything braced inside that conditional statement will be executed, while whatever is outside of it, will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="input_field" value="<?php echo $subject; ?>" />
```

In this specific case, if `$_POST['submit']` is not defined, the value is not declared. PHP will print a warning instead of what you're expecting (a blank string). You need to initialize variables like these above your `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` statement.

$_POST is only defined when the form has been submitted, so on your first view, you will see the warnings instead of empty strings.

Comment: OP is using `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` and works in conjunction with `<input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" name="submit"...` therefore `submit` is defined. Although the bracing for it will need to be moved; you're *theoretically* correct. Not to mention the missing closing `>` in `form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` so that will cause havoc.

Comment: @Fred-ii- OP specifically mentions the undefined variable error message, on first view of the page the values in his `value="<?php echo $message; ?>"` will yield a warning in practice in addition to theory!